# Wordpress automatically calls an onclick function?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, function, onclick

I'm trying to increase the height of the div **#secondary** to 750px when the user clicks on the id #1454664900670-efcca4a2-685d , so I have coded this script (tried in both WP header and footer). I don't get any errors in the Console but the problem is that the function gets called as soon as the page loads, so the div is already 750px high before I click on #secondary.

```
<script>
function expandFooter() {
    document.getElementById("secondary").style.setProperty ("height", "750px");
}
document.getElementById("1454664900670-efcca4a2-685d").onclick = expandFooter();

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> onclick = expandFooter();
> ```

You are **calling** the function and assigning its **return value** to `onclick`.

Remove the `()`.